# Setting up automated payments

Tags: paypal

We use **PayPal classic APIs**.

We have a Linux server with some application/database running on it.
Users pay pages for ocr processing.

We need to offer to our users an option to make **automatic payments** when some condition is occured.
For example: when the user have left only 100 available pages.

In this case we want to offer to user something as "**pay with PayPal 1000 pages everytime when my account have less than 100 pages**".

Is this possible to do it with PayPal API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asolutely, this is simple to accomplish. If you prefer the Express Checkout API suite, the Reference Transactions product allows you to collect permission to re-bill your customers for additional goods and services when they check out. Then you call the reference transaction API when the event you are interested in (such as the user's inventory of prepaid pages gets low) occurs.

See:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Other PayPal products support similar behavior in combination with Adaptive Payments, the RESTful APIs, etc etc.